# [openshift]How to configure CA for Artifactory to work with OpenShift

Tags: authentication, openshift, artifactory, ca

I'm using a private Artifactory repo that I'd like to use for various builds running on OCP.

Artifactory authentication is requiring CA with username and password.

The only option that I see is to either mount the CA file via config map or to extend my current s2i build by another docker build to inject the CA into the pod's file system. Both options are pretty ugly.

Is there anybody having a more elegant approach to this problem?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: If it is part of a build, you can't use a config map, look at build secrets instead. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Graham. The problem with injecting a CA via input secrets is though that (a) .crt is binary - I could probably work around that. (b) the certificate needs to be imported via command e.g. cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ How can this be achieved?

Comment: That the file is a binary is not problem as it will be stored in base64 encoded form in the resource object for the secret. As to its location, the ``destinationDir`` parameter in the build secret definition specifies where it will be copied in the image. I am presuming that will work even if destination directory would otherwise only be writable by root. So you shouldn't need a separate copy command the build secret definition should result in that being done for you.

Comment: Good point. Only thing is then to update the key store with `update-ca-trust extract`. I'm lost here...